# Working on Loop-iterations. Is there a way to call these methods and not have several "do" declarations

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

```
        //Setting my variables.

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); // Initalizing keyboard to scanner input
      int quarter;
      double balance, intrestRate;
      boolean correct = false;

        //Loop iterations to resolve error, and determine value for each input.

      do{ //Beginning loop for number of quarters, must be between 1-10
     System.out.println("Enter a number between 1 and 10 for the amount of quarters");
     quarter = keyboard.nextInt();

     if(quarter >= 1 && quarter <= 10) //If quarter is between 1 and 10
     {
        System.out.println("You have " + quarter + " quarters.");
        correct = true;
     }
     else
     {
        System.out.println("Number of quarters must be between 1 and 10");
        correct = false;
     }
     }while(!correct);

    do{  //Second loop for rate of intrest.
     System.out.println("Enter intrest rate without percent a sign. Must be greaters than 5% and less than 25%.");
     intrestRate = keyboard.nextDouble();

     if (intrestRate >= 5 && intrestRate <=25)
     {
        System.out.println("You have selected a " + intrestRate + "% rate of intrest.");
        correct = true;
     }
     else
     {
        correct = false;
     }
  }while(!correct);
 }
}
```

So, this is my code. I'm experimenting with loops, and if-else type statements. I feel like, MY approach is way to complicated and could be easily summarized or revised period. Does anyone know how to approach with, with only declaring one do statement? This code is just in the beginning phases of my experiment and has much work to do. But before I move on, I was hoping for another set of eyes!

Comment: Honeslty, I believe that your code is perfectly fine. Any alternative to merge the two loops would require you to add an additional check in the middle of it, that would actually decrease the efficiency of it.

Comment: Do you know how to use break; ? Because someone suggested using them instead of the "correct". If you do, how and where would i implement "break;"?

Comment: If you just want some suggestions you could avoid the correct boolean using while(true) and break when user do error, and maybe use local variable declaration for  intrestRate and quarter

Comment: do{ your code }while(true); instead of correct = false you just do break; This exits the loop

Comment: Then its time also that you start looking into try catch for example keyboard.nextDouble may give you an exception that is better to catch, and when everything is finished close the keyboard on finally

Comment: @PetterFriberg Better to use `hasNextDouble()` than to catch exception.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys! I will take all these suggestions into to account, i enjoy that more than what I have here

Answer (score 1):

Use of infinite loop with `break` on valid input. Enhanced to handle bad input.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

int quarter;
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter number of quarters (1-10): ");
    if (keyboard.hasNextInt() && (quarter = keyboard.nextInt()) >= 1 && quarter <= 10)
        break;
    keyboard.nextLine(); // Discard bad input
    System.out.println("Number of quarters must be between 1 and 10");
}
keyboard.nextLine(); // Discard rest of line
System.out.println("You have " + quarter + " quarters.");

double intrestRate;
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Enter interest rate (5%-25%), without percent sign: ");
    if (keyboard.hasNextDouble() && (intrestRate = keyboard.nextDouble()) >= 5 && intrestRate <= 25)
        break;
    keyboard.nextLine(); // Discard bad input
    System.out.println("Interest rate must be between 5% and 25%");
}
keyboard.nextLine(); // Discard rest of line
System.out.println("You have selected a " + intrestRate + "% rate of interest.");
```

Comment: Andreas the code it not the same as his, he does not break on good values

Comment: @PetterFriberg Sure he does. He sets `correct = true`, which exits the loop.

Comment: Damn you are right its !correct in the do while test, sorry

Comment: @Andreas ;  Thank you guys so much!

Comment: Our pleasure Dilon, make sure you accpet the answer to give some credit to Andreas